# Bootstrap v5.0 d-flex in navbar not working

Tags: css, flexbox, bootstrap-5

Here I given d-flex and justify-content-between class in the parent tag of a and div . but I cannot understand why its not working here..

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
          <div class="container d-flex justify-content-between">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
              <img width="100%" height="50" src="icons/Logo.png">
            </a>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarScroll">
              <h1>Right</h2>
            </div>
          </div>
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

so with your supplied code, you just need to add `justify-content: flex-end` to the `.navbar-collapse` section.

To complete your provided code sample, you would just add the bootstrap class `justify-content-end` to the right hand second, shown below

```html
<div class="container d-flex justify-content-between">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img width="100%" height="50" src="icons/Logo.png">
    </a>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="navbarScroll">
        <h1>Right</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

Shown in [this codepen](https://codepen.io/Jack465/pen/eYeOYej)

Comment: still it's not worked

Comment: @JNJonyHossain I put the same code you provided into a codepen, alongside my changes, you can find that [codepen here](https://codepen.io/Jack465/pen/eYeOYej)